# Next Auth: Sign-in function redirects to /api/auth/error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next-auth

I'm using Next-auth for sign-in with Google functionality on my Next.js 13 app. I'm using the `signIn()` function [documented here](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#signin). However when the `signIn()` function is called I'm redirected to http://localhost:3000/api/auth/error which displays a `404`
error. Here's the code for my sign-in button component:

```
'use client'

import { signIn } from 'next-auth/react'
import "./nav-styles.css"

export default function () {
    return (
        <li className="list-none">
            <button onClick={() => signIn()}>Sign in</button>
        </li>
    )
}
```

And here's the Nav component the sign-in button component is embedded in:

```
import Login from "./login"
import "./nav-styles.css"

export default async function nav() {
  return (
    <nav>
      <a href={'/'}>
        <h1><span className="logo-1">Addictive</span> Social</h1>
      </a>
      <ul>
            <Login />
        </ul>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

Finally, here's the `layout.jsx` file:

```
import "./globals.css";
import Nav from "./auth/nav";

export const metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className="bg-gray-20">
        <Nav />
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

You can see the full file system and the files on [GitHub](https://github.com/tech-world-code/Addictive-Socail/tree/main). I using React with Next.js 13 and TypeScript 4.9. I'm using Next-auth 4.2 for authorization. As well as Prisma DB to connect to Railway.

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from the location of your api folder. Create a new folder in the root called pages. inside it, create api folder then auth, then place the file [...nextauth].js

Folder structure pages/api/auth/[..nextauth].js

restart the server, this should work now

Answer (score 1):

As answered by André, the error is in the location of the `[...nextauth.js]` file.

Reference Link:
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#missing_nextauth_api_route_error

Suggestion of a solution:
move the file to `'/src/pages/api/auth/[..nextauth].js'`

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the url you want to use in your environment file with `NEXTAUTH_URL` otherwise it will go to your `localhost` by default. Basically it refers to your website's canonical URL